# Position image randomly after each onclick event (image must be in div tag)

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

So I am very new (as I am sure my code shows :P) and I must create code that contains an image in a div tag. It must be this way. Once the document is opened the image(div) is to be displayed at a random position. Each time the image(div) is clicked, the image alone moves to another random position. It does not replicate itself. Just moves. I have had other "better" attempts but with all my editing and changing all I get is the image in the top left corner.

I tried numerous things that all failed to work. Obviously failed because the code was terrible.
I have tried a variation of onclick events etc...I know many errors are visible. This is not one of those instances where I believe the logic is sound and it should work. This is a "what am I at" instance

```
  <script>

        function fpos () {

                var img = document.getElementById('myImage') //is this needed at all? 

                var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);      
                var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);
                var z = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);

                 
        }
            
            function rmove() {    

                img.style.top = x + 'px';                   
                img.style.left = y + 'px';
                
                
        }
             
        
    </script>

</head>

<body onload="fpos"> 
    <div style = position:absolute; onclick="rmove" >
        <img id="myImage" src='images/iasip.jpeg'> </img>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The code should be in the question itself as a textual [mcve], you can [edit] the question and add it

Comment: Hi, yes will do. I noticed my image would not upload other than a link because it is my 1st post. So Just checking out how I to upload the code. Hopefully done in a few mins.

Comment: The code should be in the question itself, not as a link or image

Comment: I got it I think. Sorry for all the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example I just threw together.

Basically you need to create a function that moves the image each time by calculating a random number for the height and width and then multiplying by the size of the window so that number can span the full width/length of the screen.

Then you can add `'px'` to the end of the calculation to use pixels as the unit and set that to the `left` and `top` properties of the image to move it that far from the left and top of the screen using absolute position (coordinates).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  move()
}

function move() {
  let img = document.getElementById('logo')
  img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + "px"
  img.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + "px"
}
```

```css
#logo {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img onclick='move()' id='logo' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/LEGO_logo.svg/2048px-LEGO_logo.svg.png' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a mill for this. Your code is doing exactly what I wanted. I believe we are to do this without the use of css.  I should have mentioned that in my original question so apologies.

Comment: Sure no problem, can you please mark this as the accepted answer if you use it by clicking the checkmark on the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Ah perfect. I tried upvoting it but again, I needed the rep points :)

Answer (score 1):

So, first, don't take this the wrong way my man but you gotta post some code to show us what you're working with. Makes all the difference for troubleshooting.

That said, you're gonna need to do with with JS. First target the image element. Can use querySelector to hit either the class or id or just getElementById.

Then add an event listener to render it at a random coordinate. Like this.

```
    <div id="imageContainer">
      <img src="your-image-source" alt="your-image-description">
    </div>
    
    <script>
      // get the image container element
      var imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
      
      // set the initial random position for the image container
      imageContainer.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + "px";
      imageContainer.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + "px";
      
      // when the image container is clicked, set a new random position
      imageContainer.addEventListener("click", function() {
        imageContainer.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + "px";
        imageContainer.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + "px";
      });
    </script>
```

Can either do that inline like in the example or add it to your script file.

Comment: Of course, I agree. I had included an image of it (was unsure how to post initially) but because I am new here I must earn 10 points otherwise it just displays a link to the image. I did get it eventually though thanks to someone who pointed that out earlier. Thanks a mill for the input and I will check it out asap :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, try to isolate some code so we can review it.

> Once the document is opened the image(div) is to be displayed at a
> random position.

By inspecting an element's properties with Right Click > Inspect > Property you'll find all javascript properties that you have access to once you select the element with a selector (document.querySelector for example)

Try something with that, i think that the easiest way is to use
element.style.transform = "translate(x,y)"
like x.style.transform = "translate(10px, 20px)";